# Which graphdb to use for user's database. (Neo4j or FB Graph API)

Tags: database, google-app-engine, neo4j, fb-graph

I need to setup a question & answer type of webapp (quite similar to stackoverflow, but at a much smaller scale) for which i need to maintain a user database also, since users will have the ownership of questions and answers.

Which kind of datastore should i use? I'm working in Google Appengine, so pls suggest things which are easily compatible and integrable with GAE.
I thought of using Graph database like Neo4j or Facebook graph db.

Also if anyone has used fb graph db, can you tell me how exactly to use it and if it will be compatible with a GAE application. And will i still need a db to store the information from fb graph api in a seperate db or that can happen on the go.?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j works well for this kind of application, see here for a possible model:

http://blog.brian-underwood.codes/2015/02/16/making_master_data_management_fun_with_neo4j_-_part_1/

Comment: Any suggestions if i can use FB graph api to store questions and answers as objects ?